# get all values from dictionary (including the values from a dictionary inside a dictionary)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

For example, if there is a dictionary like the one below, I want a function `get_dict_values()` such that

```py
dic = {1:"1", 2:"2", 3:{"a":"a", "b":"b"}, 4:"4"}

print(get_dict_values(dic))

>>> ["1","2","a","b","4"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b=[list(i.values())  if isinstance(i,dict) else i for i in dic.values()]
[i for elem in b for i in elem ]

['1', '2', 'a', 'b', '4']
```

Explanation:

```
dic.values()
dict_values(['1', '2', {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}, '4'])
```

From here we need to get either the `keys` or `values` of inner `dict` which is not clear but assuming `values` are required we need to iterate over `dic.values` and `if` it is a `dict` I need the values of the inner `dict` i.e `'a','b'` else I need just the item in the list i.e `1,2,4`.
For this we can use list `comprehension`  with `if & else`.

```
[`do this` if `foo` else `do that` for item in iterator ]  ==> if ,else ,for.
```

For our `if condition` I've used `isinstance()` to check for the inner dict and get the values of inner `dict`.
If it is not a `dict` then get me just the item.

```
isinstance(object, classinfo)

Return True if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof. If object is not an object of the given type, the function always returns False 

b=[list(i.values())  if isinstance(i,dict) else i for i in dic.values()]
['1', '2', ['a', 'b'], '4']
```

Here we got nested lists inside of the variable `b`. To break the nested lists, I've used another comprehension.

```
[i for elem in b for i in elem ] == [item for sublist in b for item in sublist]
```

It's easy to understand if we read it from the backwards.

Answer (score 1):

```
def getValues(CASE):
    if isinstance(CASE, dict):
       for VALUE in CASE.values():
          yield from getValues(VALUE)
    elif isinstance(CASE, list):
       for VALUE in CASE:
          yield from getValues(VALUE)
    else:
         yield CASE


if __name__ == '__main__':
   TEST_CASE = {
       1: "1",
       2: "2",
       3: {
        "a": "a",
        "b": "b"
       },
       4: "4"
   }

   print(list(getValues(TEST_CASE)))
```